# how set EventListener in React Native trigger when screen or Dimensions change size

Tags: javascript, react-native

i use

```
{ 
  React-Native : 0.55.4,
  React-Navigation: 2.0.1
}
```

now i want make responsive View in React Native App ( android ) , for example i use

```
 dimensions.get('window').width
```

for size of some property

now when i change screen size in Device (orientation (landscape|portrait)) and when this happen i trigger some handler to render View again and initial StyleSheet again  for new value of dimensions pass to styles

i have 2 solution,

1- use Extended StyleSheets for React Native npm package (https://github.com/vitalets/react-native-extended-stylesheet#demo)

```
  react-native-extended-stylesheet
```

2- use static dimensions.addEventListener(type, handler)

```
------------------------------------------------------
```

in first solution when i re-render App in different orientation (landscape/portrait), all thing working well , but if i change orientation styles not changed

and in second solution , i create handler for set EventListener in dimensions in  and also try this way to  set Handler on -> onLayout

```
 handleLayout(event) {

    if (this.state.dimensions) return // layout was already called
    let {width, height} = event.nativeEvent.layout;
    this.setState({dimensions: {width, height}})

   }
```

and set this handler to my Component

```
  <View  onLayout={this.handleLayout} />
```

but when i change orientation , get this erro

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating subscription.listener.apply )
```

also give this error when set listener in componentDidMount

```
 Dimensions.addEventListener("change", this.changeStyle());
```